# How to mark if completeting days are more than duration days in gantt chart in excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, gantt-chart

I have made gantt chart where I am showing duration and completed days in bar graph, like the below.

[image]

I just want to know how to mark a point where complete days has exceeded the duration days. For eg: duration is 90 days but team took 100 days, so how to mark 10 extra spent days in red color. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found.

1) Add an another column write an if condition (if("Complete days > Duration days, "Complete days - ration days","")
2) Add oanother bar grpah for these series and mark it in red. 
3) the red ones are extra days they spent than duration days.